# How to stretch and scale a single child in a container(e.g. panel, groupbox) to fit different resolution screen? C#.net

Tags: c#-4.0

Basically, I have an usercontrol as main container, inside which I have a few groupboxes and buttons. But, my interface controls will not be resized and positioned properly as what I expect in design interface.

I've already tried to change the anchor and dock properties but none of them serve my purpose.

I searched online and found something called viewbox in WPF, I'm wondering if there is something like "viewbox" in visual studio 2010?

Please help!

Comment: So I'm guessing you are not using WPF but using WinForms?  Does docking your controls not fit your needs?

Comment: I tried to change the dock property of buttons in the interface but it appears in funny style. Dock programmatically? Any suggestion?

Answer (score 0):

Try using TableLayoutPanel container and put your controls in it. It is similar to the idea of table in HTML where it is divided to rows and columns each one of them can be set to either a set of pixels or a percentage. Usually if you want to use re-sizable form, usually you should have a control that will give you good results when stretching such as image, multiline textbox etc... In addition, put the dock property to fill to get the stretching you want.

I hope this info was useful for you.